# How to get the contents of json in jsp

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

Okay I have a servlet from which I am sending back the json to ajax and then forwarding it to jsp.

This is my servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
        String complete_json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Complete JSON");
        System.out.println(complete_json);
        response.getWriter().write(complete_json);
```

This is my ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'OtherServ',
            data: {"frameID": jsonString},
            success :function(json){
                //You can also use html with hidden form
                   var form = $('<form></form>').attr('action','displayform.jsp');
                   $(form).attr('method','POST');
                   var ele = $('<input type="text">').attr('name','complete_json');  
                   $(ele).val(json); 
                   $(ele).appendTo($(form));
                   $(form).appendTo('body');
                   $(form).submit();
            } 
       });
```

This is my jsp

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var jsonString  = "<%=request.getParameter("complete_json") %>";


        var obj = JSON.parse(parsed);

        console.log(obj)



    });

    </script>
```

In th console its giving something like [object Object].Can anybody tell me if I am doing something wrong ? I am fairly new js and all. Also how to loop throough the json.

my json looks like this in servlet

```
[
  { 
     "subtype":
          [ 
            "text",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
]

}]
```

Comment: you need to esacpe the double quotes properly here or use single quotes  var jsonString  = '<%=request.getParameter("complete_json") %>';

Comment: @JYoThI Doesn't make a difference. Still, gives me the same thing on console.

Comment: first did you getting json in ajax success check it . put this code in ajax success console.log(json);

Comment: @JYoThI  Its not printing anything on the console..

Comment: because your not outputing anything in server side .

Comment: @JYoThI But I am able to print the complete_json in the servlet log...and i guess my response to the ajax call also seems fine.. so what can be the problem.

Comment: you need to use <%= ur_out_put_variable %> instead of system.out.prinln() @Sarthak Negi

Comment: @JYoThI In servlet ??

Comment: you need to return some browser out put as response of ajax request .

Comment: @JYoThI I am getting an internal server error 500 on my ajax.

Comment: url: 'OtherServ', it mean your trying to request on another sever is it ?

Comment: @JYoThI No the 500 is solved, but printing [object Object] on browser as a result of <%=out_put %>